# javascript embedded youtube video

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube

I'm writing HTML pages for a custom app. I'd like to embed youtube videos on my page. I'm aware of youtube API and I have used it in python. I'm a newbie in JS and my knowledge on html is small.

To just embed a youtube video, is pretty easy, the thing now is that there are some important requirements I cannot fulfill, listing bellow:

1) I need the video player when in "standby", to be pretty small such as 100x70 pixels. When doing that by simply embedding the video and fixing the size, the youtube's skin gets all the space, instead of only having the thumbnail.

```
    <embed
    width="120" height="72"
    src="http://www.youtube.com/v/XGSy3_Czz8k"
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    </embed>
```

2) When the thumbnail is clicked, I'd like for the player to take some more space expanding it's limits. That's another topic though, just mentioning it in case there is a simple solution that solves both.

I tried to use the youtube's api, but as I'm not experienced with JS and I didn't find a specific example to help me out, couldn't really figure how to use the API with JS. I have read a big part of it's documentation.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your video inside a container (like a div) with fixed dimensions instead of setting the dimension inside the  tag. This way you can use jQuery to change the size of the container itself instead of the .

Html:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 100px; height: 70px;"><embed
width="420" height="345"
src="http://www.youtube.com/v/XGSy3_Czz8k"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
</embed></div>
```

Simple function with jQuery:

```
$( "#container" ).click(function() {
  $(this).css("width", "420px");
  $(this).css("height", "345px");
});
```

Check out more at: 
http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Thank you for your immediate response and also for pointing out JQuery, cause it wasn't on my thoughts. The idea with the container dev, isn't working, have tried it already. The video is just getting the 420x345 size.